# Shift + home no longer highlighting correctly

Tags: keyboard, highlight, shortcut

As stated above, when trying to select the content of a field I have filled with Shift + Home no longer highlights the entire seelction, while Shift + End still will select the whole thing from the beginning of the field. Also, when holding shift and using arrows, it will only work when pressing the left arrow, leaving the field highlit. When pressing to the right I can see it high light letters one at a time, but it doesnt keep the entire selection highlit, it just moves on as if it's going to begin with the next letter, and drops the previous ones. I am sure I likely hit a keyboard shortcut combination that disabled this, but am unaware of what I may have struck, and I have been unable to find someone with the same issue while googling the problem.

Comment: Where does this happen? On your general windows or in a tool?

Comment: It would help you get a better answer if you were to give some more context... What operating system, which application?